# Facebook Page Tab does not forward

Tags: php, facebook, api

I implemented a Facebook Like Status Request on my Page Tab but if I want to click on the "next"-Link (to see index.php?action=step2) it loads the page that pops up if Like Status = Not Like. If I want to link to http://www.google.de the Page Tab doesn't load any page at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're detecting if the user likes your page or not via the `signed_request` parameter POSTed to your app's page

If so, any links the user clicks inside the iFrame containing your app will be GET requests to a different URL which will not contain the signed request with the like data - you'll need to use your own mechanism (e.g. cookies, url parameters) to pass the 'like' information from the first to second page of your app

Comment: Yeah, but even if I remove the signed_request stuff and just put a link inside there with a redirection to Google or my index.php?action=step2 NOTHING happens. Why? It looks like Facebook blocks my links / interactions.

Comment: There should be no blocking of your putting links in the page tab app, but if you're using google.de as the example URL that's probably blocked by Google's `X-Frame-Options` headers- check your developer tools to see if your browser is showing such a warning  - more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options

Comment: OK. Excluded the second step on another page without this check-thing... Thanks

Comment: Then change your page's content dynamically using JS instead of loading a new URL?